# Is this Multipilicity in class diagram correct?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

[image]

I am not entirely clear about multiplicities.

From what I understand, (1..*) close to instructor class means 1 Instructor can have many Courses.

And (1..1) near course class, means 1 class can have 1 instructor.

Is this a correct reasoning?

Note: Please ignore contents of Course class

Comment: The multiplicity in your diagram is fine.

Comment: with you saying it's fine, the [link](https://www.google.com/search?q=multiplicity+uml+diagram&rlz=1C1GCEA_enCA814CA814&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji2Nedit_gAhUJv54KHcYdCrkQ_AUIDigB&biw=1920&bih=1089#imgrc=Kok1ZCvi_yTKKM: ) this would mean one employee can have many companies. This doesn't add up.

Comment: I didn't get the **Java** part of the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the round brackets around the multiplicities are wrong. Leave them away.

Your diagram "means" that an `Instructor` has **exactly** one relation to `Course`. Additionally it has a private property `teachingCourses` as a list. The semantics ot the `1..1` is absolutely not transparent. Vice versa a `Course` has `1..*` Instructors (hopefully not at the same time). Plus it has a private property `leadInstructor` (your naming is not orthogonal here).

Now, most likely you meant this:

[image]

There's an instructor to hold 1..* courses and a course has exactly one lead instructor. I omitted the local properties and used role names marked as owned properties (the dots). That eliminates the redundancy from your diagram.

Note: as @Ister commented, `1` is a shortcut for `1..1`. Both mean "exactly one". Where a `..` appears in a multiplicity it separates lower bounds (on the left) from upper bounds (right).

Comment: Multiplicity of `1` is a shortened version of `1..1`. Formally if the multiplicity is `a` it actually means `a..a` (according to specification).

Comment: @Ister I'll add this as a note. Of course you are right.